# First 3 unknown status for $R(n)$

Tags: prime-numbers

Let

- R(1) = $1 - 1$
- R(2) = $(1\times11) - (1+11)$
- R(3) = $(1\times11\times111) - (1+11+111)$
- R(4) = $(1\times11\times111\times1111) - (1+11+111+1111)$

  R(4) is the only prime known with such form . User of math stack exchange Peter and Ian Miller had found that $R(922) , R(928) , R(964)$ are the first numbers whose (probabilistic) primality are currently unknown . Ian Miller used Mathematica prime Q method to prove that $R(490) , R(532), R(574) ,  R(592)$ are indeed composites. Could you check the probabilistic primality of $R(922) , R(928) ,  R(964) $ ? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the formula for the number of digits of R(n) :         $n(n-1)/2 + ceiling (n/22)$

Comment: $n(n-1)/2 + \lceil(n/22)\rceil$

Comment: O yes I forgot to mention that this formula is only true for $n>2$.

Comment: An implementation of `R` : `R[n_Integer?Positive] := R[n] = Module[{terms = FromDigits /@ (ConstantArray[1, #] & /@ Range[n])}, Times @@ terms - Total@terms]`